# RelativeLayout inside scrollview doesn't scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I tried wrapping my relativelayout with scrollview to be used in landscape mode but it doesn't work. I also tried wrapping my relative layout with linearlayout but it doesn't work too.

Here is the xml where relativelayout is wrapped in scrollview:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2d89ef">
    <!--Some components here-->
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

This my complete xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2d89ef">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:fontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
        android:height="20dp"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@id/btnForgot"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:fontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
        android:height="20dp"
        android:text="@string/forgot_password"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/auf_logo"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Did you add enough content to be able to scrol?

Comment: yes, I can't see some buttons when I go to landscape mode so i'm  trying to wrap this up with scrollview

Comment: do a wrapcontent for the contents inside a scrollview.. it may work for u

Comment: doesn't work either..

Comment: pls paste your xml....

Comment: edit: included the whole xml

Comment: http://pastie.org/8529914

Try This code let me know if it helps u?

It works for  me

Comment: it does work but the data are messed up, what changes did you make?

Comment: Please check my answer.. I have changed it based on your xml file..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check my below code.. It is same as your layout. So just replace it and check for it...

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#2d89ef"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="275dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:width="200dp" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:width="200dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:fontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
            android:height="20dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:width="200dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnForgot"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button"
            android:fontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
            android:height="20dp"
            android:text="Forgot Password"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:width="200dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: where's the scrollview?

Comment: I added LinearLayout between ScrollView and RelativeLayout. And relayout the view to make the UI just like yours..

Comment: @Sanket Could you please explain me how does your change fixed the problem.?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
     <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout  
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"  >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="275dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:hint="@string/username"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:fontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
    android:height="20dp"
    android:text="@string/login"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2" />

<Button
    android:id="@id/btnForgot"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:fontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
    android:height="20dp"
    android:text="@string/forgot_password"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="@drawable/auf_logo"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

   </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```