# RelativeLayout inside ScrollView won't scroll

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView style="@style/ccccc"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

         <RelativeLayout
              android:id="@+id/activity_move"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:background="#fdf1dc"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:scrollbars="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Create Your Monster"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#6D0000"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:fontFamily="serif"
                        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                  <EditText
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:inputType="textPersonName"
                       android:ems="10"
                       android:id="@+id/nameTextBox"
                       android:textAlignment="center"
                       android:textColor="#6D0000"
                       android:fontFamily="serif"
                       android:typeface="sans"
                       android:textSize="14sp"
                       android:text="Enter Name..."
                       android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
                       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

                <TextView
                       android:text="NAME"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:id="@+id/textView4"
                       android:textAlignment="center"
                       android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                       android:fontFamily="serif"
                       android:textColor="#6D0000"
                       android:textSize="18sp"
                       android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/nameTextBox"
                       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/nameTextBox"
                       android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/nameTextBox"
                       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                       android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

               <ImageButton
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_upload"
                      android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                      android:elevation="0dp"
                      style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ImageButton"
                      android:layout_below="@+id/nameTextBox"
                      android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText3"
                      android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText3" />

              <EditText
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                     android:ems="10"
                     android:id="@+id/editText3"
                     android:text="STR"
                     android:textAlignment="center"
                     android:textColor="#6D0000"
                     android:textSize="14sp"
                     android:fontFamily="serif"
                     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

             <EditText
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                   android:ems="10"
                   android:id="@+id/editText5"
                   android:textColor="#6D0000"
                   android:textSize="14sp"
                   android:fontFamily="serif"
                   android:text="CON"
                   android:textAlignment="center"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
                   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
                   android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText3" />

            <EditText
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                   android:ems="10"
                   android:id="@+id/editText6"
                   android:textSize="14sp"
                   android:fontFamily="serif"
                   android:textColor="#6D0000"
                   android:text="INT"
                   android:textAlignment="center"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
                   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText5"
                   android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText5" />

            <TextView
                   android:text="STATS"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:id="@+id/textView5"
                   android:textColor="#6D0000"
                   android:textSize="18sp"
                   android:fontFamily="serif"
                   android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                   android:textAlignment="center"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
                   android:layout_above="@+id/editText3"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

           <EditText
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                   android:ems="10"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/editText6"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   android:id="@+id/editText"
                   android:textSize="14sp"
                   android:fontFamily="serif"
                   android:textColor="#6D0000"
                   android:textAlignment="center"
                   android:text="DEX" />

            <EditText
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                   android:ems="10"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   android:id="@+id/editText2"
                   android:textSize="14sp"
                   android:textColor="#6D0000"
                   android:fontFamily="serif"
                   android:text="WIS"
                   android:textAlignment="center" />

           <EditText
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                  android:ems="10"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
                  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
                  android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2"
                  android:id="@+id/editText4"
                  android:textSize="14sp"
                  android:textColor="#6D0000"
                  android:textAlignment="center"
                  android:text="CHA"
                  android:fontFamily="serif" />

          <TextView
                  android:text="IMAGE"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                  android:id="@+id/textView2"
                  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/nameTextBox"
                  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                  android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                  android:textAlignment="center"
                  android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                  android:textColor="#6D0000"
                  android:textSize="18sp"
                  android:fontFamily="serif" />

         <TextView
                 android:text="LANGUAGES"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                 android:id="@+id/textView7"
                 android:textColor="#6D0000"
                 android:fontFamily="serif"
                 android:textSize="18sp"
                 android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

         <Spinner
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                 android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                 android:id="@+id/LanguageSpinner1"
                 android:entries="@array/langList"
                 android:prompt="@string/langPrompt"/>

         <TextView
                 android:text="First Language"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:id="@+id/textView8"
                 android:textColor="#6D0000"
                 android:textAlignment="center"
                 android:fontFamily="serif"
                 android:textSize="16sp"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
                 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
                 android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView7"
                 android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                 android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView7"
                 android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView7" />

        <TextView
                 android:text="Second Language"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:id="@+id/textView9"
                 android:textColor="#6D0000"
                 android:textAlignment="center"
                 android:textSize="16sp"
                 android:fontFamily="serif"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/LanguageSpinner1"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

         <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:entries="@array/langList" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Could anyone help me find the reason as to why this won't scroll? Inside the relative layout I have textViews, spinners and editTexts. I'm pretty new to android and xml so I have no idea why it's not scrolling.

Edit: here is the full layout as requested.

Comment: Can you paste the complete layout?

Comment: This works perfectly well for me, maybe it's whatever style you have on your `ScrollView`?

Comment: Change relative layout height to match parent! I am not sure whether this works.

Comment: Don't change the relative layout to match parent, that's incorrect. Remove the outer LinearLayout (serves no purpose). Remove `android:orientation="vertical"` from RelativeLayouts, it doesn't do anything. Also what version of Android are you using?

Comment: Please refer below link it will help you out.                                                         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391029/relativelayout-inside-scrollview-doesnt-scroll

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code you don't need the parent linear layout. Try to delete it and use the scrollView as parent. And also remove the orientation and scrollbars attributes to the relativeLayout, you don't need them.