# ScrollView not scrolling when ScrollView as parent layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-scrollview

I have a RelativeLayout inside ScrollView. But ScrollView not scrolling when it as parent layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_about_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/stack" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_about_background"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
       />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Edit: I removed `rootView.setOnTouchListener` from my fragment and `ScrollView` is working fine**

Comment: where is your scrollview end?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896963/relativelayout-inside-scrollview-not-working

Comment: @ Harshit Trivedi  Missed that line when copied. question updated

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya I know it will work if ScrollView  will put inside a RelativeLayout. But is there any alternate solution.

Comment: set height to match parent.!

Comment: @ Atif AbbAsi match_parent also will not work

Comment: @Ameer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20391606/3395198

Comment: Probably, content in the relative layout is fully visible in the screen, So it does'nt have to be scrolled

Comment: @AswinPAshok Content is more than visible screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fillViewport="false"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_about_background"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/stack" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/iv_about_background"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                   />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: @Ameer set RelativeLayout  `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: My RelativeLayout  height is match_parent. I tried ScrollView inside another layout. It works

Comment: @Ameer add Scrollview `android:orientation="vertical"
   
    android:fillViewport="false"`

Comment: Tried with android:fillViewport="false". But still not scrolling

Comment: @Ameer Please add some dummy textview .

Comment: I added a large dummy text on Textview to check if it scrolling

Comment: @Ameer My xml working . Just increase `IMAGEVIEW` Height . For test case set height `1500dp`

Comment: I found the solution. I removed rootView.setOnTouchListener from my fragment

Answer (score 2):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_about_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:src="@drawable/stack" />



    <TextView
        android:text="rgergijsojsoierjgoegorijtowjtojrtoihjorjthlbkmoijbrotoojgowijtogirtjhowortgjowjtgjwrtgjowrijgtoiwjt"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_about_background"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have changed the height-size of the image to 350dp and set text-size to 50sp to know whether the code you have posted works or not. Your code is perfectly fine but either you have to add more views inside scrollview or increase the size of the image/font-size of textview (shown in the code above).

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that you can do:

1. Make sure your content in relative layout height is more than the parent. I think 150dp and 10dp still below the parent height.
2. Change width and height of ScrollView to `fill_parent` instead of `match_parent`, and do same things to the Relative Layout.
3. Add `android:scrollbars = "vertical"` property in ScrollView

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: I tried with a large text on TextView, It is not scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it will help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_about_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/stack" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iv_about_background"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```